# Can you exclude one test method in setup? (Laravel Testing Phpunit)

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm looking for an elegant way to exclude one test method of the phpunit setup.
To explain it further you see this code:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->signUp; //creates and logs in the user
}

/** @test */
public function guest_cannot_see_request_page() 
{
    $this->get(route('requests.list'))
         ->assertRedirect(route('login'));
}
```

But I want to exclude the signIn for the guest_cannot_see_request_page() method. Since it should be a guest. For all my other methods the user is logged in.

Comment: Put that test in another file. possibly only containing the single test

Comment: There is no way to exclude "setUp" to not been processed.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Okay, I thought I remember watching a video on Laracast where you could ignore a test method. Don't remember where I have seen it, but nonetheless thank you!

Comment: You can skip a test, but that means that it will not run anything inside it. See [this](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html).

Comment: Move the test to another test case. Don't be afraid to have to have multiple test cases covering the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result if you rename your setUp() method to manualSetUp() and call it at the beginning of the test methods you that code to run on.